# Datastage Parallelism Vs Performance Improvement

Tags: datastage

How does Datastage Parallelism help with Performance improvement? What is the relationship between Parallelism and Performance?

Thanks & Regards,
Subhasree

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad - please try to be nore specific next time.

There are several differnt parallel approaches in DataStage:

1. Pipeline Parallelism: Imagine a job where data get read from a database is being transformed and written to another database. While data is still read from the database some rows get transformed and some (have already been transformed) and are already written to the target.
   Because you do not have to wait for a single step to finish this provides performamce.
2. Partitioning Parallelism: Data get read i.e. from a Sequential file and then will be split up into different data partitions (number of partitions is determined by the configuration file). Parallel stages also designed once will be instanciated one per partition and therefore extra threads will be spawned. These thread will be running in parallel and again provide a better performance (throughput).

Hope this helps.